# Odd cyclic object value TypeError in react when comparing string values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I ended up with the following code while experimenting with trying to detect a context update.  Here is the code snippet, retyped by hand so forgive obvious typos

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(!this.state.myChart || this.state.myChart.options.title.fontColor != this.context.muiTheme.palete.secondaryTextColor){

    const options = this.generateOptions(nextProps.options);

    this.state.myChart=new Chart(document.getElementById(nextProps.canvasId),
        type: nextProps.type,
        data: nextProps.data,
        options: options
    });
  } else{
    //updates data and calls this.state.mychart.upddate()
  }
}

generateOptions(nextProps){

  const defaultOptions = chartStyles.get(nextProps.style)  || Map({});  //chartStyles holds Immutable.Map maps of various default option styles
  const optionsWithTitle= this.addTitle(defaultOptions, nextProps.title);
  return optionsWTitle.mergeDeep(nextProps.options.toJs();
}

addTitle(options, title){
  return options.mergeDeep({ 
     title: {
          text: title,
          fontColor: this.context.muiTheme.palette.secondaryTextColor
     }
  })
 }
```

I receive the error cyclic object value.

Experimentation shows the issue is in my if statement comparing mychart.options.title.fontcolor to muiTheme.  if I change either side of the comparison it works.

What is it about the string comparison that could cause a cyclic object?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is in setting the state. You should be using `setState()` method there.  Also, be sure to use strict equality in your conditionals (!= vs !==)

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(!this.state.myChart || this.state.myChart.options.title.fontColor !== this.context.muiTheme.palete.secondaryTextColor){

    const options = this.generateOptions(nextProps.options);

    const myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById(nextProps.canvasId), {
        type: nextProps.type,
        data: nextProps.data,
        options: options
    });

    this.setState({myChart: myChart})
  } else{
    //updates data and calls this.state.myChart.update()
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I had tried both equality checks without it helping.  I did change to using this.setState, which I should have been doing anyways, but that doesn't stop the cyclic object error I'm afraid.

Comment: Not sure exactly what the error is from - you wouldn't get that error from a comparison. I assume this isn't cut and paste directly from your code - there a many typos - just making sure that isn't part of the issue.